# Angular rxjs: How to make multiple calls to the same API and mark and combine results

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm making multiple calls (with different payloads) to the same API and then merging the results (all arrays of objects) of all these calls together.
I have acheived this much successfully.

However I need to mark these results (each object) of each result array so that I can filter them later,

i.e. For a object coming from API call 1, I could add a property, say api_id with value "1"

Like this, object from result of API call 2 would have api_id: "2",
api_id:"3" for 3rd API call and so on...

```
    public GetTriplets(args: {payload: any, limit: number}[]) {
        const urls = [];
        args.forEach(arg => 
            urls.push(this.http.post(environment.url+ `/data/docs?limit=${arg.limit}`, arg.payload))
        );
        return merge(...urls).pipe(
            reduce((result:[], response:[]) => result.concat(response)),
            mergeMap(
                (res: []) => res && res.length > 0 ?
                    of(res)
                    : throwError('There are no docsfor the selected parameters.')

            )
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending multiple HTTP requests in parallel, then accessing all their results in one place is a good use-case for the [`forkJoin`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/forkJoin) operator.

```ts
public GetTriplets(args: { payload: any, limit: number }[]) {
  // accumulate the HTTP requests to send
  const urls = args.map((arg) => this.http.post(environment.url + `/data/docs?limit=${arg.limit}`, arg.payload));

  // send all HTTP requests
  return forkJoin(urls).pipe(
    
    // process the array of response objects for each request, in order
    switchMap((responses) => {
      ... //  mark each response (each object) of each result array so that you can filter them later
    }),

    // if any of the requests fails, emit error message
    catchError((res) => throwError('There are no docs for the selected parameters.'))
  );
```