# Show loading skeleton while waiting for image to be retrieved from server

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, amazon-web-services, express, ionic-framework

in my Ionic app, I'm showing a list of real estate properties that have images and info such a title, price, etc.
While the content is being retrieved from the database, the app displays a skeleton loading.
The property info is retrieved from a MongoDB database while the images are being retrieved from an AWS S3 bucket.

My problem is that the response from the MongoDB is a lot quicker (obviously) than the one from AWS and the skeleton loading is replaced by the actual content when I get the info of the property from Mongo, not the images. I've been trying a few methods of displaying the loaded info from MongoDB while keeping the skeleton loading for the images until they are loaded, but can't get to a solution.

This is the HTML code:

```
      <div
        class="card"
        *ngFor="let property of properties"
        (click)="viewProperty(property._id, property.tipoPropiedad)"
      >
        <swiper-container [direction]="'horizontal'" no-padding id="slider">
          <swiper-slide *ngFor="let picture of this.property.pictures">
            <img [src]="picture" alt="Foto" class="thumbnail" />
          </swiper-slide>
        </swiper-container>
        <div class="details">
          <p class="title">{{property.titulo}}</p>
          <span class="location" *ngIf="property.ocultarUbicacion !== 'true'">
            {{property.ubicacion.calle}}, {{property.ubicacion.localidad}}
          </span>
          <p class="price" *ngIf="property.operacion === 'alquiler'">
            {{property.precioFormateado}} Mes
          </p>
          <p class="price" *ngIf="property.operacion === 'venta'">
            {{property.precioFormateado}}
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
```

This is my component code:

```
async getProperties(proptype: any, operation: any) {
     this.propertiesService.getPropertiesPagination(proptype, operation).subscribe((res: any) => {
      this.properties = res.properties;
      this.page++;
      this.isLoading = false;
      res.properties.forEach(async (property) => {  
        const picuresEncoded = [];
        property.pictures.forEach(async (picture) => {
          const encodedPictureKey = encodeURIComponent(picture.Key);
          const src = `http://localhost:3000/properties/getImage/${encodedPictureKey}`;
          picuresEncoded.push(src);
        });
  
        property.pictures = picuresEncoded;
      });
    });
  }
```

This is the code of my express server that gets the image from AWS:

```
const getImage = async (req, res) => {
  const AWSs3 = new AWS.S3({
    accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_KEY,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET,
    region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
  });

  const params = {
    Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME,
    Key: req.params.pictureKey,
  };

  const data = await AWSs3.getObject(params, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(504).send("Internal error");
      return;
    }

    res.write(data.Body, "binary");
    res.end(null, "binary");
  });
};
```

Is there a way of keeping the way I get the images from the server and still show the skeleton loading while the image is being loaded?

Comment: You can do something like: `<img [src]="picture || 'path/to/placeholderImage.png'" alt="Foto" class="thumbnail" />` if picture is not loaded the placeholder image will be shown.

Answer (score 0):

> The property info is retrieved from a MongoDB database while the images are being retrieved from an AWS S3 bucket.

So what you should do is combine those calls using rxjs [ForkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin) to access all their results in one place:
[Angular rxjs: How to make multiple calls to the same API and mark and combine results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72477887/angular-rxjs-how-to-make-multiple-calls-to-the-same-api-and-mark-and-combine-re)